# Check if the function was made

Tags: javascript

So basically i need to check if the `est_wont_show` was made/fulfilled/executed.

```
function est_wont_show() {
    var HideThis, estpgt_id;

    estpgt_id = $(this).attr("estpgt_id");
//Saving in DOM

        HideThis = $("#estpgt_" + estpgt_id).detach();
        HideThis = $("#estpt_tr_for_" + estpgt_id).detach();

        if (document.body.getElementsByTagName(HideThis)) {
            //Check if element is detached
            alert("Element is in DOM");
        }
}
```

Something in this way(this function is tied up to button)

```
function TEST_ALERT() {
    if () {
        //check if function was made
        alert('hello');
    } else {
        alert('NO-2');
    }
}
```

He should check because in the end there will be 2 things. Like if the elements ARE in DOM, then he will delete them, if they are not, then he will bring them back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a global scoped variable to know if it has been executed.

```js
// We can use a flag to see if the function got executed
let est_wont_show_execution_flag = false;

function est_wont_show() {
  // Do something ...

  est_wont_show_execution_flag = true;
}

function TEST_ALERT() {
  // Did est_wont_show has been executed ?
  if (est_wont_show_execution_flag) {
    console.log('TEST_ALERT : est_wont_show has been executed');

    return;
  }

  console.log('TEST_ALERT : est_wont_show hasn\'t been executed');
}


TEST_ALERT();

est_wont_show();

TEST_ALERT();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use typeof operator to see if any function is available by the given name

```
function TEST_ALERT() {
    if (typeof est_wont_show === "function") {
        //check if function was made
        alert('hello');
    } else {
        alert('NO-2');
    }
}
```

If the function is not created **typeof est_wont_show** will be **"undefined"**